# set params in get request with jersey 2.x osisoft webapi

Tags: rest, jersey, osisoft

Hello I nedd to create a get like this:
search/query?q=name:my_machine
I'm using :

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://my_rest/api/search/query");
webTarget.queryParam("name", "my_machine");
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = 
webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

but it does not work :

I receive :
Message":"Query parameter must be specified","Source":null,"ErrorCode":3}

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but for anybody who lands here, I think you should do this:

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://my_rest/api/search/query");
webTarget.queryParam("q", "name:my_machine");
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = 
webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

The parameter name is **q**, and the value is **name:my_machine**.

Hope this helps.